# Migrating records from one table column to another table column. (rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, migration

I'm working on a rails project in which I need to take some records from one table to another table.  Its kinda straight forward.....but i've been having problems and I hope someone could help me out with it.

Basically I've got a record column named `research_consent` that is in a table named `state`, that I need to move to a new table named `configuration`.

The `research_consent` is a string in the `state` table, and remains a string in the `configuration` table.

Below I have the migration that I attempted.  I attempted to go through where the states where they had research_consent_text and then move them into the configurations table. (I got a feeling that I'm over-thinking this)

```
def change
  State.where.not(research_consent_text: ["", nil]).each do |state|
    config = state.research_consent_text
    next if state.research_consent_text.present?
    configuration.update_attributes(research_consent_text: state.research_consent_text)
    config.save
  end
end
```

If anybody could take a quick look at this and either tell me a far better way to move this, or muddle through my pitiful attempt and let me know if there is a better way, I would greatly appreciate this!

Comment: what is the table name that you would like the new data to be in?

Comment: does the `Configuration` table going to have all the states in 1 row? what is the format of this row?

Comment: @MZaragoza so the initial table is `state` and the new table is `configuration`. The column within the `state` table that needs to be moved into the `configuration` table is `research_consent_text`.  Does that answer your question?

Comment: how many rows in the configuration tables do you want?

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this

```
def change
  State.where.not(research_consent_text: ["", nil]).each do |state|
    configuration.find_or_create_by(research_consent_text: state.research_consent_text) do |configuration|
      configuration.anything_else
    end
  end
end
```

you can see more on [find_or_create_by](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/ActiveRecord/Relation/find_or_create_by)

I hope that this helps. 
Happy hacking